# autoconf substitute path in script

Tags: autoconf, automake, substitution

I have a project where there are several helper scripts that call the main executable with different command-line options. Right now, the scripts assume the executable is in the same directory, so the calls to the executable in the script look like `./my_program`. This, however, is not very flexible. What if the program is installed in the `/usr/bin` directory, and is not in the current directory?

Is there a way, using automake or autoconf, to generate these scripts, and substitute the calls to the executable with either `./my_program` or just `my_program`, depending on whether or not the executable is already installed?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. IMO the simplest solution with *autotools* would be:

- create new *m4* macro under `m4/` folder that finds a path of your program, and sets it to a variable.

  For example, you created a macro:

  ```
  MY_PROGRAM_PATH_CHECK([action-if-found], [action-if-not-found])
  ```

  This macro creates `MY_PROGRAM_PATH` variable if path is found.

  *configure.ac*

  ```
  MY_PROGRAM_PATH_CHECK(,[AC_MSG_ERROR([my_program path not found, woot?])
  AC_SUBST(MY_PROGRAM_PATH)

  AC_CONFIG_FILES([src/script1.sh], [chmod +x src/script1.sh])
  AC_CONFIG_FILES([src/script2.sh], [chmod +x src/script2.sh])
  ```
- convert your scripts to *.in* files, so the substitution would happen:

  *src/Makefile.am*

  ```
  bin_SCRIPTS = script1.sh script2.sh
  ```

  *src/script1.sh*

  ```
  @MY_PROGRAM_PATH@/my_program --option1
  ```

  *src/script2.sh*

  ```
  @MY_PROGRAM_PATH@/my_program --option2
  ```